# freemarker template for loop statement

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to create for statement in freemarker template. I am reading howto http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/ but there is just list. How can i create for statement or foreach.

```
parameter.put("size", size);
```

I want to create in freemarker template for statement like

```
for (int number = 1; number <= size; number++) {
```

Comment: I am afraid your only solution is the list statement. Why do you need other loop method ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the Freemarker manual you can do:

```
<#assign x=3>
<#list 1..x as i>
  ${i}
</#list>
```

**Edit:** Beware, if `x` is 0 (or less), it will count backwards. So you mostly want `1 ..< x`, which excludes `x` (this requires FreeMarker 2.3.22).

Comment: can i concatinate ${i} with some other parameter?

Comment: something like: ${taskDetailsDto.inputParam[''taskMsg_${i}'']}

Comment: I think yes you can do that. Did you try it ?

Comment: taskDetailsDto.inputParam['listColor_${i}'] is undefined. I can not use I like that. Any idea how can i use {i} now?

Comment: `taskDetailsDto.inputParam['listColor_${i}']` is good, only apparently you don't have some of the variables in it. What exactly is the error message? However, beware with `1..x`. If `x` is 0, it will count like: 1, 0

Comment: Expression taskDetailsDto.inputParam['listColor_' + i] is undefined . Must be Expression taskDetailsDto.inputParam['listColor_1']

Comment: @mbc: A "bit" too late but... that error message means that you don't have "listColor_1" key in the `taskDetailsDto.inputParam` map.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `list` directive:

```
<ul>
<#list 1..2 as index>
    <li>${index}</li>
</#list>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note: This only works for Freemarker versions higher than 2.3.23.

Answer (score 0):

Here size=2

```
<#list 0..2 as x>
<#if x gt 0>
${x}
</#if>
</#list>
```

output:

1

2

It will not print anything if size is zero.